# ProgressBar for Zip arhive in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a piece of code that works just fine in powershell.
However I want to visualize the amount of work (zipping process).

```
    Write-Host "Started zipping files and folders..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

    Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
    $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
    $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("$Destination\$folderName\",
        "$Destination\$folderName.zip", $compressionLevel, $false)
    if ($?) {
        Write-Host "Zip process success. Exiting..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Invoke-Item "$Destination"
        sleep -Seconds 2
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Zip process failed." -ForegroundColor Red
    }
```

I assume that what I need to put is something like:

```
Write-Progress -Activity "Zipping files and folders..." -Status "Progress:" -PercentComplete ($zip/something?)}
```

I am using Powershell v 5.1

**UPDATE:**
I will probably change and use incorporated cmdlet Compress-Archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive) it will do what you want and show a progress bar.

```
Compress-Archive -Path "$Destination\$folderName" -DestinationPath "$Destination\$folderName.zip"
```

Comment: hey, thanks! I've just updated my question. 3 minutes ago I crossed on thic cmdlet. But How can I do that? can you write some link with Compress-Archive and Write-Progress?

Comment: You don't specifically need to use Write-Progress, the progress bar is native.

Comment: I've just run it a Compress-Archive cmdlet, and I don't see any progress bar. Maybe because I am working VSCode environment for development? Thanks Update: exactly what I said - in VSCode I can't see progressbar, while when I run it through powershell.exe I see it. Thanks

Comment: Not sure on VSCode, but it doesn't show progress if you're compressing a small archive. It will show like https://i.stack.imgur.com/37JuN.png on a big archive (ignore nodejs ref it's a random screenshot from google to illustrate)